# Issue related to make a copy of List variable in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have function that accepts a Parameters of type List as follows:

```
private decimal CalculateIRR(List<AmortizationDepotResult> lstAmortizationDepotResult, decimal carryAmount)
        {

            if (lstAmortizationDepotResult.Count > 0)
            {
                var lstLoanDepots = lstAmortizationDepotResult.ToList();
                lstLoanDepots.First().Payment = carryAmount;
```

In above code, i just want to change the parameter value`(Payment)` of first object in the list. if i execute above code, `carryAmount` value gets reflect in `lstAmortizationDepotResult` as wel as in `lstLoanDepots` also. 
but i dont want to change value in `lstAmortizationDepotResult`, it should reflect only in `lstLoanDepots`.
so how do i solve my problem ???

Thanks..

Comment: Then how to make a copy ?

Comment: This isn't exactly a problem with the *list*, but the lists contains references to the same objects. As such when you do `lstLoanDepots.First().Payment = ...` you are changing the first object of `lstLoanDepots`, which is also present in the other lists. If you want each list to have unique objects you need to copy/clone these as well.

Comment: Why do i get minus point ?? is there any mistake i have made ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of objects, where your variables are not *values* but *references*.  Thus:

```
var a = new Foo();
var b = a;
a.Bar = "Hello!";
Console.WriteLine(b.Bar); // output = "Hello!"
```

If you want to copy an object's values to another identical object in such a way that they do not share the same memory space, you'll have to do that explicitly:

```
var b = new Foo
 {
    Bar = a.Bar,
    OtherField = a.OtherField
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.ToList` creates a new list but all objects contained reference the original objects. If you want a deep copy of all objects in the list provide an appropriate constructor or intialize all properties manually.

```
if (lstAmortizationDepotResult.Count > 0)
{
    var lstLoanDepots = lstAmortizationDepotResult
        .Select(x=> new AmortizationDepotResult{ 
            Payment = carryAmount, 
            Property2 = x.Property2, Property3 = x.Property3, ....
         })
        .ToList();
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement `IClonable` interface in your `AmortizationDepotResult` class:

```
public class AmortizationDepotResult ... 
  IClonable {

  ...

  Object IClonable.Clone() {
    return Clone();
  }

  public AmortizationDepotResult Clone() {
    AmortizationDepotResult result = new AmortizationDepotResult();
    ...    
    result.Payment = Payment;
    ...

    return result;
  }
}
```

So in order to have a *deep copy* you can do

```
private decimal CalculateIRR(List<AmortizationDepotResult> lstAmortizationDepotResult, decimal carryAmount) {
  if (lstAmortizationDepotResult.Count > 0) {
    var lstLoanDepots = lstAmortizationDepotResult
      .Select(item => item.Clone())
      .ToList();

    lstLoanDepots[0].Payment = carryAmount; 
    ...
  }
```